# Неправильный переход по ссылке (localhost:8080/link вместо link)

Tags: vue.js, link, route

Столкнулась с такой проблемой во Vue3:
нужно по клику перейти по ссылке и открыть ее в новой вкладке. все бы ничего, но почему-то открываеться не "чистая" ссылка, а localhost:8080/ссылка

Answer (score -1):

В результате нужно было ссылку прописать в виде:

```
const correctLink = `//${initialLink}`;
```